Trigger test from POST request to mock server on Postman
I have an API that I’m testing. I have a test on Postman that sends a POST request to my API along with a callback url on a Postman mock server. The request sends an initial response, does some processing, and then sends the final data with a POST request to the callback url on the mock server. I can see that the mock server is correctly receiving the request.
I want to know if there’s some way I can set environment variables using the request data to the mock server and then trigger another test to the api using these environment variables in the request body.
